# Full calendar eventDidMount does not execute for all events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When I navigate the week view to the month view `eventDidMount` does not execute for all events. It's only executed for the 17th and 28th of November. It's skipping the other days (1, 2, 3, 4, and 5).

`eventDidMount: function (info) {  console.log(info.event.title); }`

17th and 28th events are logged only other events skip when navigated from the week view to the month view.

[image]

I didn't find any solution for that unexpected issue.

```
eventDidMount: function (info) {

            //debugger;
            const isHolidayOrAdmin =
                info.event.extendedProps.type == "HOL" ||
                info.event.extendedProps.type == "ADMIN";
            console.log(info.event.title)

            if (info.event.display == "auto") {
                let element = null;
                const childrenDay = info.el.querySelectorAll(".fc-daygrid-event-dot");
                if (childrenDay.length > 0) {
                    element = childrenDay[0];
                }
                const childList = info.el.querySelectorAll(".fc-list-event-dot");
                if (childList.length > 0) {
                    element = childList[0];
                }

                if (info.event.extendedProps.associateWith == "Location") {
                    tippy(element, {
                        theme: $scope.tooltipTheme,
                        content: `${info.event.extendedProps.location}`,
                        arrow: true,
                        placement: "top",
                        delay: 0,

                        maxWidth: 350,
                        followCursor: true,
                        allowHTML: true,
                        animation: "fade",
                        duration: 100,
                    });
                } else if (info.event.extendedProps.associateWith == "Department") {
                    tippy(element, {
                        theme: $scope.tooltipTheme,
                        content: `${info.event.extendedProps.department}`,
                        arrow: true,
                        placement: "top",
                        delay: 0,

                        maxWidth: 350,
                        followCursor: true,
                        allowHTML: true,
                        animation: "fade",
                        duration: 100,
                    });
                }
            }
            if (isHolidayOrAdmin) {

                info.el.style.border = "1px solid black";
                // console.log($(info.el).parents('td').find('.fc-daygrid-day-number').text() )

                //console.log($($(info.el).parents('td')[0]).find('.fc-daygrid-day-number').text())
                //console.log(info.el.getElementsByClassName('fc-daygrid-day-number')[0])
                //    console.log(info.view.type)

                if (info.view.type == "dayGridMonth") {


                    $(info.el).addClass("holiday-event");
                    $(info.el).addClass("leave-top-event");
                    //$(info.el).find('.fc-daygrid-event-dot').hide();
                    //$(info.el).find('.fc-event.title').css('max-width', '60% !important');
                    //$(info.el).find('.fc-event.title').css('overflow', 'hidden');


                    info.el.style.marginBottom = "5%";
                    const dayNo = $($(info.el).parents('td')[0]).find('.fc-daygrid-day-number').text();
                    info.el.getElementsByClassName('fc-event-title')[0]?.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<span>${dayNo}</span>`)
                }

                $(info.el)
                    .closest("td")
                    .find(".fc-daygrid-day-number")
                    .css("z-index", 999999);
                $(info.el)
                    .closest("td")
                    .find(".fc-daygrid-day-number")
                    .css("color", "#fff");

                info.el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                info.el.style.zIndex = "100";
                info.el.style.textAlign = "start";

                tippy(info.el, {
                    theme: $scope.tooltipTheme,
                    content:
                        info.event.extendedProps.type == "HOL" ? `Holiday` : `Admin Day`,
                    arrow: true,
                    placement: "top",
                    delay: 0,

                    maxWidth: 350,
                    followCursor: true,
                    allowHTML: true,
                    animation: "fade",
                    duration: 100,
                });
            }

            if (info.view.type == "listMonth" || info.view.type == "dayGridDay") {
                info.el.style.fontSize = "18px";
                info.el.style.lineHeight = "20px";

                if (info.view.type == "listMonth") {
                    info.el.style.display = "revert";
                    $(info.el).find("td:nth-child(1)").attr("colspan", 3);
                    let requestNote =
                        info.event.extendedProps.description == null || isHolidayOrAdmin
                            ? ""
                            : `<span style="margin-left:15%">${info.event.extendedProps.description}</span>`;
                    $(info.el)
                        .find("td:nth-child(1)")
                        .append(
                            `<a tabindex="0" class="btn" style="pointer-events: none;padding: 0;min-width: 300px;text-align: left;color:#fff">${info.event.extendedProps.fullName}</a>` +
                            requestNote
                        );
                    $(info.el).find("td:nth-child(2)").hide();
                    //$(info.el).find('.fc-list-event-dot').hide();
                    $(info.el).removeClass("fc-list-event");
                }

                if (info.view.type == "dayGridDay") {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        let requestNote =
                            info.event.extendedProps.description == null || isHolidayOrAdmin
                                ? ""
                                : `<span style="margin-left:15%">${info.event.extendedProps.description}</span>`;
                        $(info.el).find(".fc-event-title").html("");
                        $(info.el).find(".fc-event-title").text("");
                        $(info.el)
                            .find(".fc-event-title")
                            .append(
                                `<a tabindex="0" class="btn" style="pointer-events: none; padding: 0;min-width: 300px;text-align: left;color:#fff">${info.event.extendedProps.fullName}</a>` +
                                requestNote
                            );
                    }, 2);
                }
            }

            if (info.event.extendedProps.status == "Processing") {
                info.el.style.opacity = "0.5";
                if (info.view.type == "listMonth") {
                    $(info.el)
                        .find(".fc-list-event-graphic")
                        .append(
                            `<i style="margin-right:5px" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
                        );
                } else {
                    $(info.el)
                        .find(".fc-event-title")
                        .append(
                            `<i style="margin-right:5px" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
                        );
                }

                const el = info.el.querySelectorAll(".fa-exclamation-circle")[0];
                tippy(el, {
                    theme: $scope.tooltipTheme,
                    content: `Pending`,
                    arrow: true,
                    placement: "top",
                    delay: 0,

                    maxWidth: 350,
                    followCursor: true,
                    allowHTML: true,
                    animation: "fade",
                    duration: 100,
                });
            }
            $("#divEmployeeContainer").css(
                "max-height",
                $("#div-calendar").height() - 65
            );
            $("[data-date='" + $scope._selectedDate + "']")
                .find("th")
                .addClass("list-highlight");
            //console.log($("[data-date='" + $scope._selectedDate + "']").find('th'))

            window.setInterval(function () {
                $(".fc-dayGridDay-view")
                    .find(".fc-highlight")
                    .removeClass("fc-highlight");
            }, 10);
        },
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your issue including relevant code and event data. We cannot find bugs in pictures. See also [ask]. Thanks

Comment: At a guess, if you switched from the first week of November to a view of the whole month November, then probably the top row of dates were already rendered on the previous view? If so, then I'd guess fullCalendar just moves that across to the new view and doesn't actually need to add the events to the DOM again, which would explain why eventDidMount doesn't run - it doesn't need to. But that's just a guess...if you want more help please provide the code and data as I mentioned above.

Comment: Actually, in "eventDidMount" I customize the event base on events props. Buts it's reverted back to the initial state like a normal event.

Comment: Also, add the 'eventDidMount' function ... Plz check if you can understand.

Comment: As I requested, please provide a [mre] of the issue. In this case that's going to involve your fullcalendar config code and some event data, so that we could load your calendar, see the events, and follow the same process you describe in order to see this issue. If you're saying the problem is that eventDidMount isn't executing at all, then it seems likely that the inner content of that function isn't really relevant to the problem.